# Can you replace frequently used lines of code by a function in Python?

Tags: python, function

Can you replace frequently used lines of code by a function?

Let's I say have multiple functions similar to `loop(matrix)` so I have to write those for-loops every time. Would I be able to replace those 2 lines by 1 function like `check(matrix)`.

from this:

```
def loop(matrix):
    for row in matrix:
        for col in matrix:
            #do something
```

To this:

```
def check(matrix):
    for row in matrix:
        for col in matrix:

def loop(matrix):
    check(matrix):
        #do something
```

This returns an invalid syntax error.

EDIT:
My questions is to replace ANY code so for example:

Original function:

```
def check_down(matrix, highestProduct):
    for y in range(len(matrix)):
        for x in range(len(matrix)-3):
            product = 1
            for i in range(4):
                product = product * matrix[x+i][y]
            highestProduct = check_highProd(product, highestProduct)
    return highestProduct
```

Im looking for something like this:
It replaces lines of code but doesn't print or return anything.

```
def check_down(matrix, highestProduct):
    for y in range(len(matrix)):
        repeat()
            highestProduct = check_highProd(product, highestProduct)
    return highestProduct

def repeat():
    for x in range(len(matrix)-3):
            product = 1
            for i in range(4):
                product = product * matrix[x+i][y]
```

Comment: Did you try this? What was the issue?

Comment: yes, yes you can

Comment: of course you can call the function multiple times if the code is same

Comment: @Akaisteph7 I tried this but it just gave an invalid synthax error.

Comment: That is what you should mention in your question. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If what you are trying to do is to create some sort of variable that Python will replace with lines of code then that is not possible.**

---

Yes, the purpose of functions is precisely to not have to repeat code.

Your issue with your code is that you have a colon after your function call. It is not a function declaration so there is no need for a colon. And since it is not a declaration, you cannot do something *inside* of it in `loop(matrix)` as you are trying to do, only add code in `check(matrix)`.

Lastly, you need to have some code after your for loops or that will also create an error. See the proper format for this:

```
def check(matrix):
    for row in matrix:
        for col in row:
            # Do something

def loop(matrix):
    check(matrix)
    # Do something else
```

You need to have the `# Do something` portion in your `check(matrix)` be the same for this code to be reusable. If all you need to reuse is the for loop declarations, then you have two options: just rewrite them or see MrGeeks's answer.

---

EDIT: Python does not work the way you are asking about so it is not possible. I do not see what the problem is with using this code in a function though. It's basically what you are trying to do but with the correct syntax.

I removed my example and will just adapt the code you showed. You have to return `highestProduct` as it does not exist. There is no point in not returning it.. If what you are trying to do is to pass a "reference" to the variable and update it, you still need to create `highestProduct` first. See my answer below:

```
def check_down(matrix, highestProduct):
    for y in range(len(matrix)):
        highestProduct = repeat(matrix, highestProduct, y)
    return highestProduct

def repeat(matrix, highestProduct, y):
    for x in range(len(matrix)-3):
        product = 1
        for i in range(4):
            product = product * matrix[x+i][y]
        highestProduct = check_highProd(product, highestProduct)
    return highestProduct
```

Comment: Im not sure if you understand my question correctly but seems like the answer is: "no that is not possible" ?

Comment: @NielAgneessens I am giving you directions as to how you should properly use function declarations. As to your specific problem, the purpose of for loops is to iterate over a structure and get a specific element each time. I think MrGeek's answer describes how you can properly use those for-loops results in the way you were trying to in your question. Let me know if that still does not make sense.

Comment: My question wasn't necessarily targeted at loops, I just wonder if you can replace any lines of code by a function. Lets say I have a program that has 5 lines that reoccur 5 times; can I just put them in some type of function as if they are still there? So I write 5 lines instead of 25.

Comment: @NielAgneessens My code tells you exactly how to do that. I am not sure what it is you don't understand. See my example and let me know.

Comment: I edited my question with an example that should make it clear. I understand how functions work but functions can only return a value or print something, they can't replace lines of code.

Comment: @NielAgneessens Functions in Python replace lines of code by returning a value. I think you are misunderstanding the point of functions. And I do not see the benefit of trying to do what you are saying, it only brings confusion.

Comment: @NielAgneessens I updated my answer. See the changes. the answer is that it is not possible to do what you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate values at demand using the `yield` keyword, making the `check` function a generator, which will reduce the number of loops to one in later iterations on the matrix:

```
def check(matrix):
    for row in matrix:
        for col in row:
            yield col

def loop(matrix):
    for col in check(matrix):  # <-- iterate the matrix with one loop
        print(col)

loop([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: @Akaisteph7 The question has been edited 2 days after my answer.

Comment: The edit just added more explanations. The question is still the same.  I guess you don't have to do anything but just wanted to let you know.